# HTML Email not displaying font-family correct in Outlook 2010

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, outlook, font-family

I'm trying to send an HTML email through rails but it keeps displaying with Times New Roman on Outlook
Gmail on Linux renders it correctly, Gmail on Windows also renders it correctly
When I receive on Outlook, it shows a button "show this email on browser" or something like that, and it shows it correct there
I've tried to add a font-family tag on the body, in a specific element but it just doesn't seems to matters

this is the HTML code rendered on Gmail

```
<div style="line-height:20px;color:#333333;font-size:12px;font-family:&quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0">
<table cellpadding="20">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<img alt="Logo" src="http://www.simplificpavarini.com.br/assets/logo.png">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<h3 style="color:#b0232a;margin-bottom:20px">Cotas Diárias - 26/07/2013</h3>
<table style="width:800px;line-height:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd">
<thead><tr style="background-color:#ddd">
<th style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left;width:160px">Fundos</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px;width:120px">Cota</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">Dia</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">Mês</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">Ano</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">12m </th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">PL*</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">PL 12m*</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">AAA ALLOCATION FIC FIM</td>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">
22,89476146
</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">0,10%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">0,22%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">2,90%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">7,55%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">45.526</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">45.649</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f9f9f9">
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">% CDI</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">322%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">55%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">76%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">109%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">AAA SELECTION FIC FIM</td>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">
2,39205680
</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-0,04%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">0,15%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">2,75%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">5,93%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">3.083</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">3.926</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f9f9f9">
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">% CDI</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">37%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">72%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">86%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">AAA AÇÕES FIC FIA</td>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">
12.285,04135694
</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">0,72%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-1,42%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-5,49%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">3,08%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">20.227</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">20.245</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color:#f9f9f9">
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">Vs. Ibovespa</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-0.87%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-0.18%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">17.61%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">19.53%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table style="width:800px;line-height:20px;margin-bottom:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd">
<thead><tr style="background-color:#ddd">
<th style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left;width:160px">Índices</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px;width:120px"></th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">Dia</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">Mês</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">Ano</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">12m</th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></th>
<th style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">CDI</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">0,03%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">0,12%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">3,55%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">6,60%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:70px;padding:6px;text-align:left">Ibovespa</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">1,60%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-3,57%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-24,92%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px">-18,42%</td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
<td style="width:70px;text-align:center;padding:6px"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div style="margin-top:20px;text-align:justify;font-size:10px">
* R$ Milhões
</div>
<div style="margin-top:20px;text-align:justify;font-size:10px">
<p style="margin:0 0 32px;margin-bottom:16px">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it!
I need to define font-size and font-family for every td in the table
so I did

```
* {
  font-family: ...
  font-size: ...
}
```

Comment: Apparently you have to in-line everything. Great article about this: http://devblog.orgsync.com/2013/03/29/designers-workflow-for-html-emails-in-a-rails-app/